Error while adding to cart Invalid state change requested Magento 2.4
When user try to add product in cart it giving error Invalid state change requested. This happens for few logged in customer. We using default REST API for add item to cart. The issue happens in Magento 2.4
How I can fixed the issue? Please help

were you able to install the patch and fix the problem?

You may encounter the following known issue:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-27/acsd-48694-invalid-state-change-requested-error-prevents-customer-from-placing-order
You may apply the patch ACSD-48694. The instruction is included so you may apply the patch and see if it fixed.
